# Maximum number of non-intersecting edges

Tags: graph-algorithm

There are N nodes in a plane and they are connected by straight lines called edges. 
What is the maximum number of non-intersecting edges?

Comment: Graph edges do not intersect.

Comment: The tag graph-algorithm is indeed misleading, however, in the question it is stated that the points lie in a plane.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you are looking for is `2*N - 3`. This is the number of edges if the N nodes are triangulated, with bounded triangles. Then every bounded face forms a triangle, i.e., no more non-intersecting edges can be added.

Starting from 3 nodes it is easy to see that we can add at most three bounded non-intersecting edges. Then for every additional node we can add two more edges.

If the unbounded face is triangulated as well, i.e., unbounded edges are allowed, then there are `3*N - 3` edges.